# Spring boot project with Gradle does not runs spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

i'm working with Ubuntu, IntelliJ and Gradle 4.8.1

Onece the project created, if i try to debug it, the Gradle Daemon starts, build the projet ends up without run the spring boot

my Gradle properties ARE:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.8.1-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

and the console log is:

```
8:32:06: Executing task...

Starting Gradle Daemon...
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:39247', transport: 'socket'
Gradle Daemon started in 5 s 356 ms

> Task :help

Welcome to Gradle 4.8.1.

To run a build, run gradle <task> ...

To see a list of available tasks, run gradle tasks

To see a list of command-line options, run gradle --help

To see more detail about a task, run gradle help --task <task>

For troubleshooting, visit https://help.gradle.org

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 17s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
8:32:23: Task execution finished.
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:39247', transport: 'socket'
```

and it is how my build.gradle looks like:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.0.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.ITAcademy'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')/* {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine' //ojo que en 2.1.9 esto no sale
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()*/
}
```

thanks

Comment: what command do you use to run a project?

Comment: Hello @SeydazimovNurbol, i just use the debug option in intelliJ

Comment: I think, there is a problem with IntelliJ Idea. When you try to run your app through terminal, is it works?

Comment: How can run it through the terminal? i've run other projects with gradle and intelliJ before, so i do not thing that it would be an intelliJ problem, but a project configuration problem. thanks @SeydazimovNurbol

Comment: `./gradlew clean build` to build a project. Then, `java -jar build/libs/(There should be name of you jar file)` to run a project. If you don't know name of your jar file, just tap to `Tab` button, after you typed `java -jar build/libs/`

Comment: Task 'clean' not found in root project 'daus'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207917/discussion-between-raul-magdalena-catala-and-seydazimov-nurbol).

Comment: hello all.. is this issue resolved ? I am also facing same issue. bootRun is successful but tomcat server has not started as below.

> Task :bootRun
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 3542

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.8.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 10s
7 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 6 up-to-date
20:35:22: Task execution finished 'bootRun'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the Gradle output indicates that the `:help` task was run, that is the `help` task on the root project, the issue is most likely that you did not specify which task to run.

- You can add the task to run to the command line or the IntelliJ configuration. For a Spring boot project, it is most likely something like `bootRun`.
- You can [define the default task in your project](https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:default_tasks)

And please, do not use `clean` in Gradle, you will slow your build for no good reasons as incremental builds is at the core of the Gradle features.